# How to avoid that Vim autowraps a line that ends with a given character (or set of characters)

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I have auto (hard) wrapping enabled in Vim. That is, whenever I write, the lines are automatically wrapped according to the textwidth. That's OK.

Now, my question is: is it possible to set VIM so that it does NOT wrap a line if it ends with a specific character (or a set of characters)?

Here there is an example.

Let's say that I want "%" to be my "nowrap" character.

Now, if I type: "abc abc abc abc % <enter> abc"

I'm currently getting:

```
abc abc abc abc % abc
```

while I want:

```
abc abc abc abc %
abc
```

These are my current (relevant) settings:

```
textwidth=80
wrapmargin=0
formatoptions=a2tqcrl
nolinebreak
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, neither your example. You do type <enter> and don't get a linebreak? And why it would be useful to selective autowrap?

Comment: For text, autowrap is really good. But when you write in latex, sometimes you have an itemize/enumaration, and the autowrap screws everything up. So it would nice to "disable" autowrap just by putting an extra char, for example, at the end of the \begin{itemize}.

Comment: To add more details: I do get the linebreak, but as soon as I start to type again, the break is gone.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in; see `:help fo-table`. The only workaround I can think of is toggling `'formatoptions'` (or `'textwidth'`) via an autocmd:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * execute 'setlocal fo' . (getline('.') =~# '%$' ? '-=' : '+=') . 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! But it doesn't seem to work :/ The problem is that this will remove the "a" from fo for each line ending with %. However, the line that gets (but should not) autowrapped is the one "after" the line ending with the %. As another note: I noticed that (with the standard settings) the autowrap gets disabled if I have a line that starts with % (i.e., a comment). Maybe there is way to tell vim to not mix text and comments?

Comment: Yes, this admittedly is just a raw demo to get you started; it still needs some tweaking (like considering the line above, as you've found out).

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is about latex, have you checked the [existing plugins on the subject?](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=latex&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search)

In special, the following plugins possible address your problem:

- [AutoAlign : Automatically align as you type (autoalign): bib c c++ html maple matlab tex vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=884)
- [Align : Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294)
- [LaTeX Box : Lightweight Toolbox for LaTeX](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3109)

Comment: Latex is only one example. My question was more vim-specific, to see how/if it would be possible to implement the requested behavior. I hoped there was some obscure formatoptions-related flag I was not aware of...